# /Users/srsifat/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/srsifat/voice_assistant.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x

/Users/srsifat/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/srsifat/voice_assistant.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
what can i do to set my directory. iam using macos sonoma